# Is mmap the most efficient method for Inter-Process Communication?

Tags: linux

mmap provides a way for process to write to and read from memory, there is not need for process to switch to kernel mode when to write/read. Less system calling means more efficient.
Other methods for inter-process communication ,such as pipe, socket, usually have to switch to kernel mode when do read/write.
So, as I can see, mmap is the most efficient method for inter-process communication. Is it right?

Comment: probably the fastest, but that is only applicable for applications residing on the same computer, it can't be used in distributed IPC

Comment: I think you mean "fastest", not "most efficient".

Comment: I am absolutely not sure that less system calling equates to more efficient..... (even if indeed avoiding useless syscalls is preferable). BTW, pipes are also efficient (and the performance depends a lot on buffer sizes!). I would measure various solutions (and you'll be surprised).

Comment: And while `mmap` is a method for IPC, it is not a method for *synchronization* which you would also need.